# Dependency Injection with serenity-cucumber spring

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I am writing auto-test for web app using cucumber, serenity and spring in Java. I have 3 separated files with step definitions classes. One test includes steps from different step definition classes and I need to use only one exemplar for WebDriver and some of my own helpers for all step definition classes. How can I do it?

P.S. Tried to create TestData.class, which contains all needed data and use @Autowired annotation to create TestData object, but as result I received three exemplar of TestData and three different browser

Comment: I suggest you share some code, it about configuration and the Test class, thus you are helping us to help you.

Comment: Thx for ur help, but I found solution for my task by static java class with lazy initialization of WebDriver and using cucumber @After hook to stop browser